# what term/identity/theorem states that given a triangle the largest angle must be opposite the longest side?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

I'm having a hard time finding a proof or what this concept is called:

given triangle ABC, if angle A > angle B > angle C, then side BC must be the longest side of triangle ABC

Comment: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI18.html . See also prop19

Comment: I call this the Three Bears Theorem: *"The Papa Bear side is opposite the Papa Bear angle, the Mama Bear side is opposite the Mama Bear angle, and the Baby Bear side is opposite the Baby Bear angle."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such result is known as:

"The side of a triangle opposite the largest angle is the longest side."

You can find its proof in any plane Euclidean geometry book.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: you know what just as I read that I found in my axiomatic geometry book, called the scalene inequality >:( I spent so much time looking for it!

Comment: @ConsistentToast I am glad to know you found it. Have nice studies!

Answer (score 1):

It is a result of the law of sines:

$$\frac{\sin A}a=\frac{\sin B}b=\frac{\sin C}c$$

This means tha the largest of $a,b,c$ corresponds to the largest of $\sin A,\sin B,\sin C.$

Assume $A$ is the largest angle.

If $A\leq \frac\pi2,$ then, since $\sin x$ is increasing on $[0,\pi/2],$ $\sin A$ is the largest of the sines, so $a$ is largest.

If $A>\frac\pi2,$ then $\sin(A)=\sin(\pi-(B+C))=\sin(B+C),$ with $0\leq B,C\leq B+C<\frac\pi2.$ So $\sin A\geq \sin B,\sin C,$ and again $\sin A$ is the largest value, and hence $a$ is the longest length.

---

Alternatively, more geometrically,  find the circle which goes through $A,B,C,$ and then, at least for $A,B,C$  acute angles, the lengths of the sides and the lengths of the corresponding arc lengths, and the arc lengths correspond to twice the opposite angle.

You then have to deal with the obtuse case separately. Not hard to do - type get the length corresponds to the arc of $2\pi-2A=2B+2C>2B,2C$ and thus $a$ is still longer then both $b,c.$